# How to force a fixed position div to scroll to its top after adding content with jQuery load

Tags: jquery

How can I scroll a fixed position'd div to its top after injecting content via jQuery.load()?

I have an off-screen div. On a button click, it jQuery load()'s content into it and appears. At the bottom of the now visible div there's a previous/next pagination. The pagination loads the previous/next block of content, but the scroll position stays near the bottom where the pagination is.

I want it to re-position back to the top of the fixed div once the new content loads.

So far, I've tried and failed with:

`$('.fixed').load('content.php', function() { $(window).scrollTop(); }`

and

`$('.fixed').load('content.php', function() { $('.fixed').scrollTop(); }`

Comment: `scrollTop()` is the getter. To set the value use `$('.fixed').scrollTop(0);`

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was close.

Answer (score 0):

Was missing the a scrollTop() value:

`$('.fixed').scrollTop(0);`